# How can we add to the default response codes in Spring docs Open API on actuator endpoints such as /health?

Tags: java, spring, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, spring-actuator

I am able to display the actuator endpoints in my API through this config:

```
springdoc:
  show-actuator: true
```

I am able to manage the http mappings of my /health endpoint with this config:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      status:
        http-mapping:
          down: 500
          fatal: 500
          out-of-service: 500
```

With this config, Open Api UI says the return codes of my /health endpoint is 200 and 404.  I would like it to say 500 too.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OpenApiCustomiser`: This sample add a 500 error for only your `/health` endpoint.

```java
    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser healthOpenApiCustomiser() {
        return openApi -> openApi.getPaths().entrySet().stream().filter(stringPathItemEntry ->  stringPathItemEntry.getKey().equals("/health"))
                    .forEach(stringPathItemEntry -> stringPathItemEntry.getValue().readOperations().forEach(operation -> {
                        ApiResponses apiResponses = operation.getResponses();

                        ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse().description("Custom Error")
                                .content(new Content()
                                        .addMediaType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, new MediaType()));
                        apiResponses.addApiResponse("500", apiResponse);
                    }));
    }
```